# Devise token auth and Axios (rails api and react)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, devise, axios

I am running into an issue when trying to validate a token that is currently saved client side. I am using a react front end client with a rails api backend.

I am able to acquire the token and send it over in an axios get request, however the rails API backend gives me a 401 error.
[error from console, reflects in rails server log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfq0O.png)

If I use the same data as the token within POSTMAN and send the request it processes just fine and gives me the user information.

The only difference I can tell is that postman is properly letting me set the headers as 'application/json' but axios is not on the react side.(if I don't set postman for that content type I get the same error.)

Here is the rails server response to the two separate requests. One processes it as */* and one as HTML.
[Rails Server log to requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/662BM.png)

Here is the actual request itself:
[trying to set params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdm4Z.png)
[basic axios request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9IUC.png)

Comment: Could you show controller's code?

Comment: Hi Robert any success on this issue?

Comment: I actually ended up going a different route for validating the token with fetch since axios was being difficult.